# Can an AppDomain in .NET load an assembly that has a reference to a native dll?

Tags: .net, interop, appdomain

I try to load a Managed C++ assembly with references to native projects in to an appdomain but it doesn't seem to load the native parts in to its image and an access memory violation exception is thrown when stepping over code from a the native dll. Are native dll's not supported in AppDomains?

Comment: Doesn't the native stuff need to be regsvr32:ed? You can't load unmanaged stuff into the AppDomain.

Comment: you can load unmanaged code into a new app domain. You may run into problems with dll path location if you're loading assemblies by filename, and the assembly is in a different path to the current dll.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Showed that an option in the project properties had to be checked for it to work (Debugging->Enable unmanaged code debugging)